# Node.js error in Vaadin Spring Boot application

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, vaadin

Trying to run [Creating CRUD UI with Vaadin project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/) in `Intellij IDEA` thar contains following `build.gradle` :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:14.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Got node problem while run project:

```
2020-10-07 19:01:42.637  INFO 8364 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Installing node version v12.18.3
2020-10-07 19:01:42.637  INFO 8364 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-win-x64.zip to C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node-v12.18.3-win-x64.zip
2020-10-07 19:01:42.638  INFO 8364 --- [           main] ProxyConfig                              : No proxies configured
2020-10-07 19:01:42.638  INFO 8364 --- [           main] FileDownloader                           : No proxy was configured, downloading directly
2020-10-07 19:01:52.244  INFO 8364 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Unpacking C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node-v12.18.3-win-x64.zip into C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\tmp
2020-10-07 19:01:54.523  INFO 8364 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Copying node binary from C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\tmp\node-v12.18.3-win-x64\node.exe to C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\node.exe
2020-10-07 19:01:54.524  INFO 8364 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Extracting NPM
2020-10-07 19:02:21.733  INFO 8364 --- [           main] NodeInstaller                            : Local node installation successful.
C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\node.exe: bad option: --no-update-notifier
C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\node.exe: bad option: --no-audit
C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\node.exe: bad option: --scripts-prepend-node-path=true
2020-10-07 19:02:22.336 ERROR 8364 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Command `C:\Users\g\.vaadin\node\node.exe --no-update-notifier --no-audit --scripts-prepend-node-path=true install` failed:

2020-10-07 19:02:22.336 ERROR 8364 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : >>> Dependency ERROR. Check that all required dependencies are deployed in npm repositories.
2020-10-07 19:02:22.340 ERROR 8364 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize Vaadin DevModeHandler
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The version of Node.js that comes with vaadin is the problem. Install the latest version of Node.js. Go to its installation directory copy node_modules folder and node.exe and replace those in C:\Users~.vaadin\node.

Comment: Hello! Have you faced a similar problem and tried this and, if so, did it work out? I just think this might be a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes. That was a comment. The cause is I haven't 50 rep, but I've faced the same problem and that helps me. So I decided that it may help someone else.

Comment: OK, now I understand. I think you should be more assertive in your answer, instead of just stating "try something", explain what you did a bit more detail and how that solved your problem. And if so, that's not a comment, but an answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me was help:

1. install npm,
2. add path to PATH
3. restart console/ide.